# In MySQL how to set index to the table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

In MySQL how to use the Index concept for MySQL tables.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax for adding index to existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX column_name
```

A simple example

```
CREATE TABLE employee_records (name VARCHAR(50), employeeID INT);
CREATE INDEX id_index ON employee_records(employeeID);
```

creating index while creating table

```
CREATE TABLE employee_records (
    name VARCHAR(50), 
    employeeID INT, INDEX (employeeID)
);
```

Comment: I tried the 3rd method..along with foreign key reference...it wasn't working.........!!!!!!!

Comment: This should be better explained: CREATE INDEX id_index ON employee_records(employeeID); Is it an index with id? The first example with "alter.." works

Comment: 3rd method is causing a syntax error for me for some reason, seems to fail using W3Schools too http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_create_table

Answer (score 1):

To add an index to a table in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] ADD INDEX ([column name], ...);
```

Comment: it is not clear that the index is added to an existing table btw.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX **index_name** (**col_name**)

OR

CREATE INDEX **index_name** ON **table_name(index_name)**