# How do I tune mysql slow query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I want to optimize this mysql query. It is supper slow in my case as it takes 5.6 second to execute.I used profiler to sort out the issue but I don't have much knowlege about database. My query is here:

```
SELECT 
                        n.name,
                        n.computedmeaning,
                        m.origin,                             
                        m.gender,
                        m.pronunciation,
                        m.similar,
                        m.variants
                        FROM
                        names n
                        INNER JOIN meta m ON m.nameid = n.id
                        WHERE m.religion = 'hindu'
                        AND n.computedmeaning IS NOT NULL ORDER BY n.name LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I only have `PARIMARY INDEX "id"` on `meta` table and `PRIMARY INDEX "id"` on `name` table also full text search is enabled on name table. here is screen shot:
[image]

At last here is my profiler screen shot alerts:

[image]

Comment: your query looks fine.. give index for the fields in where condition

Comment: `FULLTEXT` is useful only for "words" and `MATCH...AGAINST...` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Give **index** for the field `religion` and `computedmeaning` .

Refer [In MySQL how to set index to the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731048/in-mysql-how-to-set-index-to-the-table)

The CREATE INDEX statement is used to create indexes in tables.

Indexes allow the database application to find data fast; without reading the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Using Index will surely decrease the run time of your query.

However, you can try the below query. It will give you better performance.

```
SELECT 
       n.name,
       n.computedmeaning,
       m.origin,                             
       m.gender,
       m.pronunciation,
       m.similar,
       m.variants
  FROM
       (SELECT * 
          FROM names 
         WHERE computedmeaning IS NOT NULL) n
 INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
               FROM meta 
              WHERE religion='hindu') m ON m.nameid = n.id 
 ORDER BY n.name LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names:  INDEX(name, computedmeaning, id) -- in this order
meta:   INDEX(name_id, religion)     -- in either order
```

That `names` index *may* consume the `ORDER BY`, thereby saving a sort.  It is also "covering", which helps with performance.

That `meta` index should be efficient for the `JOIN`.

See also [*Cookbook on indexing*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN ` in front of `SELECT` to produce an "explain plan" of your query. This is the first tool to use for performance tuning a query. But I think the indexes suggested by Rick James above will help a lot. To help your understanding perhaps run an explain plan, then add the indexes, and then run another explain plan for comparison.